# Не работает часть сайта на Joomla после переноса на другой сервер. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: php, сервер, joomla, windows-server-2008-r2

После переноса сайта на Joomla с Server 2003 (apache) на Server 2008 (iis) все компоненты сайта перестали работать, из-за чего может быть данная проблема и как ее можно решить если весь остальной сайт и Joomla работают корректно?

Версии php и mysql не менялись при переносе.

Comment: сравните правила `web.config`  с `.htaccess`, убедитесь в наличии нужных прав к директориям у IUSR

Comment: Сравнил правила web.config с .htaccess; Все без каких-либо замечаний, более того ничего нового при переносе в них не добавлялось. А у IUSR есть все необходимые права.